# something is wrong with numpy.zeros_like in vscode

Tags: python, numpy, visual-studio-code

I'm using numpy.zeros_like to generate a N X D dim array where N and D both greater than 1. My vscode tells me that array does not support item assignment when i try to change one row or column

```
import numpy as np 
a=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
b=np.zeros_like(a)
b[0,:]=[1,2,3]
print(b)
```

i think there is no problem in the code above but my vscode tells me that "b does not support item assignment"

Comment: you;re missing the opening square bracket, no? `b[0,:]=1,2,3]` what were you trying to do here, `b[0,:]=[1,2,3]` ? Regardless, your current code is a syntax error, please check and fix the code, or we cannot help.

Comment: sorry, i did forget it lol. And i'm working on cs231n assignment 1. they use dw=np.zeros_like(w) to generate dw matrix

Comment: So, the code now works just fine for me. Did you try running it in a fresh session? i do not have vscode though, is this some kind of "warning" rather than an error message? does the code work fine for you?

Comment: you'd have to come up with the shortest amount of code that actually reproduces the problem. Please create a [mcve]

Comment: yeah, it can run in vscode. and the output is [[1 2 3] [0 0 0]]

Comment: i think this the shortest way to reproduce my problem. i think there is absolutely no problem in my code, but vscode always tells me that " does not support item assignment". my code can run and gives correct output in vscode